# Retrieving a specific value from an array to the custom cell - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm playing around with custom cells.
With the great help from the stackoverflow community i've been able to put some code together. I'm able to fetch array values from a text string into a custom cell uilabel and uibutton, but the issue is - the fetched result is always the last object in the array.

Here is the code

```
func setUpQuestion()
{

// setting variables
var Question: String?
var option1: String?


// using a text string with custom separators

    let text = ">>Here is the grocery question\n>>and another one\n--Apples\n-
-Oranges\n[pickApples]pickOranges\n[pickApples2]"

// splitting this string into four different arrays depending on the separator 

    let lines = split(text) { $0 == "\n" }
    for line in lines {
        if line.hasPrefix(">>") {
            Question = line.substringFromIndex(advance(line.startIndex, 2))
        } else if line.hasPrefix("[") {
            if let index = line.rangeOfString("]")?.startIndex {
                option1 = line.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(
                    start: advance(line.startIndex, 1), end: index))
            }
        }
    }

// creating variables for appending the values - here I'm using a custom class called QuestionMark created in a separate .swift file 

    var question1 = QuestionMark(Question: Question!, option:option1!)
    var question2 = QuestionMark(Question: Question!, option:option1!)

// appending the values into uilabel and uibutton in the custom cell

    arrayOfQuestions.append(question1)
    arrayOfQuestions.append(question2)

}

// regular tableView protocol functions

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
    section: Int) ->Int
{
    return arrayOfQuestions.count

}

func updateCount(){
    if let list = mainTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath] {
        rowsCount.text = String(list.count)
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: CustomCellForTableViewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomCellForTableViewTableViewCell

// the SetCell function i'm using here was created in a separate .swift file

    let quest = arrayOfQuestions[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(quest.Questme!, optionone: quest.optionize!)

    cell.optionOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return cell

}
```

Here are the additional codes i'm using for the class and setCell function

```
class QuestionMark
{

var Questme: String?
var optionize: String?

init(Question: String, option: String)
{
    self.Questme = Question
    self.optionize = option
}

// separate swift file
func setCell(Question: String, optionone: String)
{
    self.mainText.text = Question
    self.optionOne.setTitle(optionone, forState:UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

As a result in both cells i'm getting the last object from the text string and it looks like this

```
And another one - PickApples2
And another one - PickApples2
```

How do i start appending cells from the first array value and then move forward to second,third,fourth ?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: add the your cellForRowAtIndexPath code. so we can help you better

Comment: @Karlos, added the required code. please look in the original post.

Comment: can you try this in cellForRowAtIndexPath ----> cell.textLabel?.text = arrayOfQuestions[indexPath.row]

Comment: @Karlos, there is an issue with this approach - i'm appending values into two objects (uilabel and unbutton) using the arrayOfQuestions, not just the textLabel. The suggested method in that case would return an error.

Comment: Did you tried button.tag = indexPath.row and add all your button details to that button?

Comment: I think i've came to the core of the issue - the code for separation returns me single strings, not arrays.

Comment: After your code separation don't forgot to add these lines for button in the cell 
 -- > cell.addSubview(button) --> cell.bringSubviewToFront(button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the syntax of the text to parse is pretty complicated ;-) …

Second of all, the problem to get always the last object is that you create the array of questions after the repeat loop. At that moment the variables `question` and `option` contain always the last found string.

Here a solution:

- After getting a question a new object `QuestionMark` is created and appended to the array (without the `optionize` property)
- After getting an option the appropriate `QuestionMark` object is fetched from the array by an index counter, the property `optionize` is set and the counter is increased.

Two notes:

- Variable names should always start with a lowercase letter. Even the syntax highlighter of StackOverflow follows that naming convention.
- In my solution all variables are non-optionals.

---

```
class QuestionMark
{

  var questme: String
  var optionize: String

  init(question: String, option: String = "")
  {
    self.questme = question
    self.optionize = option
  }

...
```

---

```
var arrayOfQuestions = [QuestionMark]()

func setupQuestion() {

  let text = ">>Here is the grocery question\n>>and another one\n--Apples\n--Oranges\n[pickApples]pickOranges\n[pickApples2]"

  // splitting this string into four different arrays depending on the separator

  var counter = 0

  var question = ""
  var option = ""

  let lines = split(text) { $0 == "\n" }
  for line in lines {
    if line.hasPrefix(">>") {
      question = line.substringFromIndex(advance(line.startIndex, 2))
      let questionMark = QuestionMark(question: question)
      arrayOfQuestions.append(questionMark)
    } else if line.hasPrefix("[") {
      if let index = line.rangeOfString("]")?.startIndex {
        option = line.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(
          start: advance(line.startIndex, 1), end: index))
        let questionMark = arrayOfQuestions[counter]
        questionMark.optionize = option
        counter++
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the insight. i've tried the solution and i'm getting a blank uitableview. I'm also wondering how we fix this part of code then
`let quest = arrayOfQuestions[indexPath.row]
cell.setCell(quest.Questme!, optionone: quest.optionize!)`

Comment: sorry, re-phrasing my question a little: i've fixed the lines of code below accordingly to the solution yet still getting a blank screen `let quest = arrayOfQuestions[indexPath.row]
cell.setCell(quest.questme, optionone: quest.optionize)`

Comment: add breakpoints and `println()` lines to make sure that the appropriate methods are called at all

Comment: worked amazingly! just changed the setupQuestion function spelling) my lousy mistake. thank you so much for the support!

Comment: Hi vadian! Is there a way to actually limit the output to a specific number of objects along these lines `let questionMark = QuestionMark(question: question) arrayOfQuestions.append(questionMark)`? In case if i just want to output 1 or 2 questions and then proceed after users input. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend to parse the whole text and use a temporary property to save the `QuestionMark` objects. Then you can use them in any kind you like.